# Correct Data structure to be used for the given problem - Java

Tags: java, json, data-structures, collections, set

I want to process the subset of values in Java.
The scenario is like

**Example 1:**

```
IDA - {x, y}
IDB - {x, y, z}
IDC - {z}
```

This should be clubbed in a JSON as follows,

```
{data : {x,y}, issuer: {IDA, IDB }}
{data : {z}, issuer: {IDB, IDC }}
```

**Example 2:**

```
IDA - {x, y, z}
IDB - {y, z}
IDC - {z}
```

JSON structure should be

```
{data : {y, z}, issuer: {IDA, IDB }}
{data : {x}, issuer: {IDA }}
{data : {z}, issuer: {IDC }}
```

Here, I would like to have idea about using the correct data structure in Java.

Note: In the given example, the data is taken with three entries. But , there may be 'n' number of entries.

Comment: Can you give a description of how `localIDA - {x, y}` looks in Java?

Comment: And specify what kind of library you're using to parse JSON? Jackson, Gson...

Comment: The localIDA - {x, y} is represented as HashMap<String, List<String>>

Jackson library is used for JSON parsing.

Comment: Ok, what about library for marshaling/unmarshaling JSON?

Comment: The only issue I am thinking about is the Java processing to extract the correct data to form JSON.
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper is the class used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arrange the data in the desired way, we can use a couple of *intermediate maps*.

Also, we would need a few custom types to perform transformations and to store the final result that would be serialized into JSON. I'll use Java 16 [*records*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) for that purpose (but they could also be implemented as classes).

```
Map<provider, List<data>>

           | + intermediate transformation: 
           v   entry -> group of objects `provider + data`

Map<data, Set<provider>>

           |
           v

Map<Set<provider>, List<data>>

           |
           v
List of custom type that would be serialized into JSON
```

These are the main steps:

- Split every *entry* of the *initial map* into a group of *custom objects*, each holding a reference only one reference to `data` and `provider`;
- Group these objects by data and form the first auxiliary map of type `Map<String, Set<String>>` (providers by data).
- Iterate over the entries of the newly created map and rearrange the data by grouping the entries by *value*, which is of type `Set<String>` (set of providers) into the second auxiliary map of type `Map<Set<String>, List<String>>`. The values of the second map would contain `data`-strings mapped to identical sets of providers (set is used to make the comparison not sensitive to ordering of providers).

  - **Note** that in this case it's safe to use a **mutable** collection (*which can be created via* `Collectors.toSet()` *- see the code below*) as a *map-key* because we need it only to perform intermediate transformation, and we're **not storing** references neither to the *keys*, no to the *map*. But if the reader would want to use a piece of the solution provided below to generate a map which would be stored as a field and passed around, then to avoid accidental changes the *key* should be represented by an **immutable** collection. Therefore, to make the solution more versatile, I've `Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()`.
- The final step is to generate a `List` of objects that would be serialized into JSON. For that, we need to iterate over the second *auxiliary map* and turn each entry into a custom object.
- The data is ready to be marshaled into JSON. For demo-purposes, I've used [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (reader can apply any other tool of their choice).

*Custom objects:*

```
public record DataProvider(String data, String provider) {}
```

```
public record DataProviders(Set<String> data, List<String> providers) {}
```

*The map logic:*

```
Map<String, List<String>> dataByProvider = Map.of(
    "localIDA", List.of("x", "y"),
    "localIDB", List.of("x", "y", "z"),
    "localIDC", List.of("z")
);
        
List<DataProviders> dataProviders = dataByProvider.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
        .map(data -> new DataProvider(data, entry.getKey()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        DataProvider::data,
        Collectors.mapping(DataProvider::provider,
            Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet())
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(
        HashMap::new,
        (Map<Set<String>, List<String>> map, Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry) ->
            map.computeIfAbsent(entry.getValue(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(entry.getKey()),
        (left, right) ->
            right.forEach((k, v) -> left.merge(k, v, (oldV, newV) -> {
                oldV.addAll(newV);
                return oldV;
            }))
    )
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new DataProviders(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT); // to make the output look nicely (can be omitted)
        
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(dataProviders);
        
System.out.println(json);
```

*Output:*

```
[ {
  "data" : [ "localIDB", "localIDA" ],
  "providers" : [ "x", "y" ]
}, {
  "data" : [ "localIDB", "localIDC" ],
  "providers" : [ "z" ]
} ]
```